# Who else to contact about missing luggage?

Tags: jfk, ams, lost-luggage

I flew JFK-->AMS-->HER.  The first leg was operated by KLM and the second by Transavia.  I bought my ticket through Delta.  At JFK, they checked my bag all the way to HER, even though my layover at AMS was 22 hours.  Upon arrival at HER, my bag did not arrive.  I filed the usual "Property Irregularity Report" and there has yet to be news.

Was I supposed to have picked up my bag in AMS even though it was tagged all the way to HER?  Was it a mistake of the check-in staff at JFK to through check it on such a long (overnight) layover?  (I was not at all surprised it didn't make it to HER).  Is there anyone else I can contact besides to keep checking back with the lost luggage office at HER? (I know how to check the status on worldtracer).  Would it be helpful to call the AMS airport lost and found? or Delta or KLM?

Comment: JFK = New York City; AMS = Amsterdam; HER = Heraklion in Greece.

Comment: I had similarly bad experience with KLM and AMS airport. I was flying from Dublin via AMS to Kyiv (Ukraine) 3 times and all 3 times my luggage has not arrived to Kyiv on the same plane as me. It seems like due to busy AMS airport and short layover KLM could not manage to transfer my luggage to the second flight. I filed the report same as you did and it took them 2-3 days to deliver my luggage. When I was asking for updates I did not receive any, so I had to wait patiently. In your case it is more strange as layover was 22 hours

Answer (score 7):

If you purchased your Ticket through Delta, they will be responsible for your baggage. You should file a claim through the [Delta baggage claim website](https://www.delta.com/bags/claimLanding.action).

They will then take care of your reimbursement and then bill the baggage handler internally.

Also, if they checked your baggage through, which is a normal thing outside of the US, even for long layovers, you have done nothing wrong by not picking up your baggage.

Answer (score 1):

> Was I supposed to have picked up my bag in AMS even though it was tagged all the way to HER?

No. If it's checked through and there is a big HER  on the baggage tag, you can't pick it up since they not supposed to put it out on the carousel in AMS in the first place.

The typical cut off time for not checking baggage through is 24 hours, which turns a "layover" into a "stopover".